# Avro Schema Evolution With GenericData.Record - Mapreduce process

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, avro

I have a mapreduce program that reads data from the avro data, processes it and outputs avro data. I have a schema for this avro data, lets say with 4 columns.
I use GenericData.Record to write the avro data.

Now i create a pig relation on top of this data with the schema that has 5 columns. The 5th column, which is new has the default value defined in the avsc file.
As per my understanding, i should be able to read the old data (which was generated with 4 columns) using the new schema with one additional column.
Instead i get an error that says - **Trying to access non-exist column.**

**What am i missing?**

**Mapreduce driver code**

```
Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf());  
job.setJarByClass(DeltaCaptureMRJobDriverWithSameSchema.class);
job.setJobName("CDC");
job.getConfiguration().setBoolean("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive", true);

//This is required to use avro-1.7.6 and above
job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first", "true");
FileInputFormat.addInputPaths(job, args[0]);
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

job.setInputFormatClass(AvroKeyInputFormat.class);
job.setMapperClass(DeltaCaptureMapperMultiPaths.class);
Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File(args[2]));
AvroJob.setInputKeySchema(job, schema);
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(AvroValue.class);
AvroJob.setMapOutputValueSchema(job, schema);

job.setOutputFormatClass(AvroKeyOutputFormat.class);
job.setReducerClass(DeltaCaptureReducerMultiPaths.class);
AvroJob.setOutputKeySchema(job, schema);
job.setOutputKeyClass(AvroKey.class);

return (job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

**Mapper code**

```
public class DeltaCaptureMapperMultiPaths extends Mapper<AvroKey<GenericData.Record>, NullWritable, Text , AvroValue<GenericData.Record>> {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(DeltaCaptureMapperMultiPaths.class);

    @Override
    public void map(AvroKey<GenericData.Record> key, NullWritable value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        try {
            System.out.println("Specific Record - " + key);
            System.out.println("Datum :: " + key.datum());
            System.out.println("Schema :: " + key.datum().getSchema());
            AvroValue<GenericData.Record> outValue = new AvroValue<GenericData.Record>(key.datum());
            System.out.println("Generic Record (out) - " + key.datum());
            context.write(new Text(key.datum().get("id") +""), outValue);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Reducer Code**

```
public class DeltaCaptureReducerMultiPaths extends Reducer<Text, AvroValue<GenericData.Record>, AvroKey<GenericData.Record>, NullWritable> {

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text  key, Iterable<AvroValue<GenericData.Record>> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        for(AvroValue<GenericData.Record> value : values) {
            AvroKey<GenericData.Record> outKey = new AvroKey<GenericData.Record>(value.datum());
            context.write(outKey, NullWritable.get());
        }
    }
}
```

Lets say MR outputs to /etl/out. Now the following pig script fails with the error that i described in the beginning.

```
a= LOAD '/etl/out' USING org.apache.pig.builtin.AvroStorage('hdfs:///etl/test.avsc')
b = FOREACH a GENERATE $0,$1,$2,$3,$4;
```

hdfs:///etl/test.avsc has 5 fields in it (5th is new).

Comment: If you do `dump a` in pig, how does that look like?

Comment: dump a gives the values of 4 fields. Ideally i would expect 5 fields with the 5th being null as the avsc has 5 fields in it.

Comment: describe a also gives only 4 fields. Looks like its not taking the avsc passed in the AvroStorage constructor!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected, the issue is actually in the way AvroStorage was used. The usage is: **a= LOAD '/etl/out' USING org.apache.pig.builtin.AvroStorage('test','-schemafile file:///etl/test.avsc')**, assuming that the test.avsc is in the local file system. Keeping the avsc in hdfs also should work but i did not get around to test that. I am not sure why there is no clear cut documentation on these!!!!

Comment: Found a nice article with some more info: http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/07/04/using-avro-in-mapreduce-jobs-with-hadoop-pig-hive/#pig Confirms that HDFS location works as well. Also explains `no-schema-check` option.